# Error in UPDATE syntax using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

I'm trying to run an `UPDATE` and I'm getting a syntax error. I'm using php and PDO to create the `UPDATE` command. What is wrong with my syntax?

> UPDATE education WHERE userId = :userId AND fieldId = :fieldId SET
>   fieldId = :fieldId, educationTitle = :educationTitle, educationDegree
>   = :educationDegree, startDate = :startDate, endDate = :endDate, educationDescription = :educationDescription;

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE userId = '35' AND fieldId = '4' SET fieldId = '4',
>   educationTitle = 'ththt' at line 1

UPDATE:

I've tried placing `WHERE` after `SET` like the sample below, but I'm still getting a syntax error.

> UPDATE education SET fieldId = :fieldId, educationTitle =
>   :educationTitle, educationDegree = :educationDegree, startDate =
>   :startDate, endDate = :endDate, educationDescription =
>   :educationDescription, WHERE userId = :userId AND fieldId = :fieldId;

Comment: wrong usage of where clause.

Comment: **what** error you're "still getting"? What is the **text** of this error? How we are supposed to solve your problem without seeing the error message?

Comment: @YourCommonSense The error message is in the question above.

Comment: "error message is in the question above" clearly shows SET after WHERE. So, ether you didn't change the code or new error message is a different one.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm sorry. You're right. I forgot to post the updated error message. However, the question was solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put `WHERE` after `SET`.

```
UPDATE  education  
SET     fieldId = :fieldId, 
        educationTitle = :educationTitle, 
        educationDegree = :educationDegree, 
        startDate = :startDate, 
        endDate = :endDate, 
        educationDescription = :educationDescription
WHERE   userId = :userId AND 
        fieldId = :fieldId
```

Comment: I tried that first, but I get the same error.

Comment: @relentless I guess you have mess something else, try it again using the statement above.

Comment: I tried again. same error. Is the use of a comma here correct or not `:educationDescription, WHERE `?

Comment: remove the `,` before the `WHERE` clause. It should be `:educationDescription WHERE `

Comment: Thanks, it was the comma